# How to return a vector of null terminated const char*?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I am trying to read a file, line-by-line.
Convert each line into a null terminated string.
Push all the lines into a vector and return it.

```
vector<const char*> TypeGLscene::LoadGLshader (string ThisFile)
{
ifstream fromFile;
fromFile.open(ThisFile);
if (fromFile.good()==false)
{
    cout<<"Could not find file: "<<ThisFile<<endl;
    exit(1);
}

vector<const char*>  FileContents;
const char*    OneLine;
string         LineStr;

while (fromFile.good()==true)
{
    getline(fromFile,LineStr);
    OneLine = LineStr.c_str();
    FileContents.push_back(OneLine);
}

fromFile.close();
return FileContents;
```

The problem is that all the char strings are created in the stack and the function returns a vector of char* to nowhere.

I am attempting to allocate memory on the heap by:

```
OneLine = new char[LineStr.size()+1];
```

but I get stuck, because once allocated I cannot copy anything into it; the contents being const.

How on earth am I going to use the new keyword on a const char* and add contents to it at the same time before it realizes it's a const ?

(Not to mention that I would then have to delete them one by one, on the other side ... what a mess)

EDIT:
I would rather return a vector but all this is because I don't know of a quick (one line) way to convert a vector into a const char** for:

```
void glShaderSource(GLuint shader,
                    GLsizei count,
                    const GLchar **string,
                    const GLint *length);
```

Comment: Any reason why you can't return a `std::vector<std::string>`?

Comment: Why do the vector elements need to be `const char *`?  Consider just making them `string`s, or if you really need `char *` then allocate them the C way.

Comment: because glshaderSource expects an array of const char* and if I cave in and give the whole shader in a single line then I am not getting useful compiler error messages (all errors end up in line 1, if the whole shader is in one line)

Comment: You don't need to have one string per line to get correct messages, you just need to have \n characters at the end on each line (ie. read the whole file, not line per line with getline). The multiple strings in glShaderSource are meant to be used when code comes from different files.

Comment: @Jerem. I didn't know this. I tried it as a single string with \n per line and it works too (and it gives line numbers for the compile errors). Thanks for the tip !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Returning a `std::vector<char*>` is fraught with problems.

1. You'll have to allocate memory for each line. The client of the function must add code to deallocate memory. The client code becomes more complex than it needs to be.
2. The client function must know whether the `char*` were allocated using `malloc` or `operator new`. They have to follow the appropriate method for memory deallocation based on the method used to allocate memory. Once again, the client is burdened with knowing too much about what the function does and how it does it.

A better method is to return just a `std::vector<std::string>`.

```
std::vector<std::string>  FileContents;
std::string LineStr;

while (fromFile.good()==true)
{
    getline(fromFile,LineStr);
    FileContents.push_back(LineStr);
}

fromFile.close();
return FileContents;
```

If you must return a `std::vector<char*>`, you can use:

```
std::vector<char*>  FileContents;
std::string LineStr;

while (fromFile.good()==true)
{
    getline(fromFile,LineStr);
    char* line = new char[LineStr.size()+1];
    strcpy(line, LineStr.c_str());
    FileContents.push_back(line);
}

fromFile.close();
return FileContents;
```

Comment: It's a private function (in which case I am the client and have to deal with all that on the other end, and I don't like it one bit).

If only I knew a quick one line way to feed a vector<string> into void glShaderSource(GLuint shader, GLsizei count, const GLchar **string, const GLint *length);

Comment: Pretty sure there is no such way.

Comment: @ThomasAn, in that case, use the second block of code from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert then call `glShaderSource` in C++11 from a

```
std::vector<std::string> vec;
```

using

```
{
  std::vector<const Glchar*> veccstr 
     = std::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 
                      [](const std::string&s){
                         return static_cast<const Flchar*>(s.c_str()); });
  glShaderSource(shader, veccstr.size(), veccstr.data(), &length);
}
```

Read about C++11 [std::vector::data](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/) & [std::transform](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/)

I am assuming a `typedef char Flchar;` somewhere in your (OpenGL?) library, or at least

```
static_assert("Flchar same size as char", sizeof(Flchar) == sizeof(char));
```

BTW we all know that `sizeof(char)` is always 1, so you might code `sizeof(Flchar)==1` instead in your `static_assert`

Answer (score 0):

Combining Sahu's and Jerem's suggestion I completely changed strategy and simply returned (from the file reading function) a single string with newline characters per shader line:

```
string TypeGLscene::LoadGLshader (string ThisFile)
{
   ifstream fromFile;
   fromFile.open(ThisFile);
   if (fromFile.good()==false)
   {
       cout<<"Could not find file: "<<ThisFile<<endl;
       exit(1);
   }

   string  FileContents, oneLine;

   while (fromFile.good()==true)
   {
       getline(fromFile,oneLine);
       FileContents += (oneLine + "\n");
   }
   fromFile.close();
   //FileContents=FileContents.c_str();
   return FileContents;
}
```

and then just fed that one string to the glshaderSource

```
char* ShaderChapters[1]; ShaderChapters[0]=&fileContent[0];
GLuint VertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
glShaderSource(VertexShaderID,1,ShaderChapters,0);
glCompileShader(VertexShaderID);
```

Nonetheless, Sahu's answer still stands as the most accurate given the wording of the original question.